# After having installed 12.04 get error message from update-manager

Tags: update-manager

I want to download updates but I get this error message:

```
Das Herunterladen der Paketdateien ist gescheitert...
Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/gnome-control-center-data_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.3_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.30 80]...
```

If I enter `http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center` into a browser window, I can see `gnome-control-center-data_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.4_all.deb`,
but not `gnome-control-center-data_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.3_all.deb` (observe bold **`4`**, **`3`**!).

Comment: It's best to try again in a few hours, the servers are probably being updated with new packages

Comment: The package lists are probably out of date. Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: @EricCarvalho I recommend posting this as an answer. (Even if it doesn't work for this OP, it works in most similar situations. And it will almost certainly work here, because the problem is that the server's version is *newer* than the version known about on the local machine.)

Answer (score 1):

If the above works then ok...
I had the same problem.

Try this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope it works for you.